# Convert string to hex array data

Tags: c++

I'm editing a file with hex data.
For example, in my code I have this:

```
const char data1[4] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD};
file.write(data1, 4);
```

This works great. I open the file with a hex editor and can see AABBCCDD.

**But** when I get hex data via input from the user, I don't know how to format it. It comes as a string, it may be `AABBCCDD`. But if I write this to my file, I will get the ASCII hex values that represent A, A, B, B in my data.

I want to convert my string with hex values into a char array like my `data1` above.

I searched and came across some code, which I thought can help me.
I changed it and came up with this but it doesn't seem to work, and want to know if there is a better way.

```
char* hxStringToHxArray (std::string hxinput)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    char* outputchar = new char[(hxinput.length())/2];
    unsigned int buffer;
    int offset = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    while (offset < hxinput.length()) {
       ss.clear();
       ss << std::hex << hxinput.substr(offset, 2);
       ss >> buffer;
       outputchar[0] = (static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer));
       offset += 2;
       pos++;
    }
    return outputchar;
}
```

Maybe there is some problem with the code, but if there is a better way of doing this I'm happy to hear.
I will not be dealing with hex strings of dynamic lengths, I will always know the length, it that helps.
Thanks.

EDIT.
Ah I just realized I had a mistake in my example data at the very top. I updated it, sorry.

Comment: You need to *parse* the input data.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "hex array". There's just numbers/values. You could have also written `{0, 1, 10, 11};`. You write numbers to the file -- depending on the editor you use for opening these get interpreted as hex numbers, ASCII characters or even mutli-char characters.

Comment: Impressive memory leak there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - It must be obvious C++ is not my strong point, otherwise I wouldn't be asking for help with something like I'm asking about, right? Please tell me about the memory leak, if you don't mind.
For the others, thanks for the input.

Comment: Google `C++ new` or look it up in your book and study the examples.

Comment: Oops, some lefts overs when I tried to make my variable names more suitable for sharing! Thanks.
But that code wasn't the main thing, that was just to show the idea, I wanted to see if there were any other better ways to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either write your own parser, or use `std::strtol`. Either one should work. Here's a home-brew implementation that assumes that the characters `A`–`F` and `a`–`f` are encoded contiguously:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

unsigned char parse_hex(char c)
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') return c - '0';
    if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F') return c - 'A' + 10;
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f') return c - 'a' + 10;
    std::abort();
}

std::vector<unsigned char> parse_string(const std::string & s)
{
    if (s.size() % 2 != 0) std::abort();
    std::vector<unsigned char> result(s.size() / 2);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != s.size() / 2; ++i)
        result[i] = 16 * parse_hex(s[2 * i]) + parse_hex(s[2 * i + 1]);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: [Demo](https://ideone.com/mbqLVJ)

Comment: Thank you for the help. The demo is great at playing around and seeing what is going on. Thank you for sharing this with me.

Comment: @zljepwqp I just tested, for me my solution works fine as long as you use `int` and then just cast to `char`. You do not need to write your own parser if C++ provides one for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it to complicated:

```
int main()
{
    int input[10];
    for (int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cin >> std::hex >> input[i];
    }
}
```

This is of course without error-handling but should do what you want:

1. get string input in format `0xAB`
2. interpret it as hex, ie. store it as number with size `char` (usually equals `unsigned short` I think)

EDIT: When using a char-array C++ tries to smart-ass and gives you the ASCII value instead. You can just get int values and try casting them depending on what you want to do exactly.

The complete code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    int input[10];
    char c[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cin >> std::hex >> input[i];
        std::cout << "Hex input: " << std::hex << input[i] << "\n"
            << "Hex input as Dec: " << std::dec << input[i] << "\n";

        c[i] = static_cast<char>(input[i]);
    }

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("/tmp/file.txt");
    myfile.write(c, 10);
    myfile.close();
}
```

Input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
A
B
C
D
E
```

In the file:

```
$ hexdump -e '/1 "%#X "' /tmp/file.txt
0X1 0X2 0X3 0X4 0X5 0XA 0XB 0XC 0XD 0XE %
```

Comment: [Are you sure](https://ideone.com/i4xuOp)?

Comment: Thanks for the demo, the code seemed too simple compared to what other implementations I read about.
So even though it's not what I want, thanks for your time.

Comment: I forgot that C++ tries so hard to be intelligent and sees "Oh, there's a char, let's convert it to char". It works fine if you use an int array though.

Comment: Demo: http://ideone.com/lfEPPR